# Finding maximum (max) text-item in a list using python

Tags: python, text, max

Why is it that the max function operates differently in the two list below:

```
>>> list1=['the school','boy', 'the wise old man']
>>> max(list1)
'the wise old man'

list2=['made', 'with', 'then', 'happy home', 'came', 'this', 'them', 'from', 'have', 'into']
>>> max(list2)
'with'
```

Obviously in list2, `'happy home'`is supposed to be the `'max'` as it has more number of text than the others in the list.

Any ideas why?
Thanks.

Comment: Be very careful what you consider "obvious".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`max()` compares strings lexicographically; you found the element that would be sorted last. Thus, `'the wise old man'` comes after `the school`, alphabetically speaking.

To get the *longest* string instead, pass a function to the `key` argument of `max()`:

```
max(list2, key=len)
```

Generally speaking, without a `key` function, `max()` will find you the value where `value > othervalue` is always true for all other values in the input sequence.

The `key` argument, if provided, gives `max()` a different value to compare to decide what item in the sequence is the largest.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik: which must be a callable. I am simplifying here for a beginner.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @MartijnPieters, nice and straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the list item which has max size. you should use like this

```
max(list2, key=len)
```

the result is

```
'happy home'
```

key changes the behavior of max function, on other hand it find max item which has max length.